# Are any of the four incorrect and why?

Tags: difference, infinitive-vs-gerund

- They suggested a walk in the park.
- They suggested that we walk in the park.
- They suggested walking in the park.
- They suggested to walk in the park.

As I see it. All of them are correct and I can't see any difference between them.

Comment: The last is wrong. You can't "suggest" to do something. "They wanted to walk in the park" is OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last is wrong. You can't "suggest" to do something. "They wanted to walk in the park" is OK. – Mick